# How to override taskmanger and home button pressed

Tags: android

I am making a app which have an activity similar to calling screen and i don't want user to cancel it. So i want to override homeButton press and stop user to open android's default task manager. Same as a calling screen. Please help me us because i didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

The home button can not be overridden for security reasons.
You can override back button but they have disabled the option for home.

[This link gives information on overriding hardware buttons](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didn't helped me, i know about this already!